# Carefully closing processes

Tags: c#, .net, service, process

Main goal is to close Process and not to leave any hanging connections, sub-processes behind.

There is a simple service that's running 24/7 and every minute it is checking if there is any new job to start. If it finds one, it starts its

```
  public Process StartProcess(string pathToExecutable, string arguments)
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName        = pathToExecutable,
                Arguments       = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow  = true
            };

            return Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        }
```

And when trying to close

```
   public bool TryCloseProcess(Process process, int waitSeconds)
        {
            try
            {
                process.CloseMainWindow();
                process.WaitForExit(waitSeconds);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Any proper way to be sure that all resources would be released, etc ?

Comment: No, you do not have control of the resources that process uses. IMHO the best approach would be looking at how that process handles its resources. For .NET related code you could start with some reading on IDisposable and Garbage Collection

Comment: @bradbury9 I got some knowledge on IDisposable  and GC but is there any specific you have in mind ?  Like try to force GC run, etc ?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge on what processes you are starting? Can they be anything, or are they some managed executables implemented in your organization?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes, I know, and have full control over it. Me and my colleague developed that  app.exe

Comment: I mean do you know what apps you are starting with `Process.Start(processStartInfo);`? Is this the same app.exe you are talking about? In that case (as @bradbury9 mentioned) you need to focus on resource clean-up on exit in that app.exe. You cannot do it remotely, but what you do in this scheduler app is sufficient. The app.exe should handle the rest.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Sorry for unclear answer, yes the app.exe Is the process being started.

And only way to (clear/try clear) when closing process is just making sure all resources implement IDisposible and additionally tying to call GC when disposing ?

Comment: When you stop a process, any managed (and also unmanaged) resources it utilized will be freed whether you dispose them or not. There will be no leak since the full working set will be freed by your OS. What you should see is whether there are ongoing processing (threads started by you, which are not marked with IsBackground = true will continue running and prevent application close), and you should implement graceful exit for any kind of external connections etc. during close. Can you handle an event on app.exe which tells you that the application is closing?

Comment: @OguzOzgul There is some Tasks and Threads running in this app.exe
meaning if I dispose everything correctly, this  process.CloseMainWindow();
 should work fine ?

Comment: It depends on what the tasks are doing. If one of the tasks is writing to a file at that exact moment, the file will be partially written. If a thread at that time is doing some Network IO at that moment, that will be interrupted. It will be disconnected from the remote end prematurely. You don't need to worry about memory and handle leaks but should consider graceful stop for these kind of processes (file IO, network IO etc.)

Comment: @OguzOzgul ah.. Thats what I needed to hear :) Now  I get the bigger picture ! If you would post this as answer I would gladly accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus on resource clean-up and graceful exit in the process you've started.

You cannot do it remotely, so what you do in this scheduler app is sufficient to send a message to the started process to make it stop.

The started process should handle the rest. (A graceful exit)

When you stop a process, any managed (and also unmanaged) resources it had utilized will be freed whether you `Dispose()` them or not.

There will be no memory leak since the full working set will be freed by your OS.

What you should consider is whether there are ongoing background processing (threads started by you, which are not marked with IsBackground = true will continue running and prevent application close), [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) that you have started, and you should implement graceful exit for any kind of external connections etc. for these.

If one of the tasks is writing to a file at that exact moment, the file will be partially written. If a thread is doing some Network IO at that moment, that will be interrupted. It will be disconnected from the remote end prematurely. You don't need to worry about memory and handle leaks but should consider graceful-stop for these kinds of processes (file IO, network IO etc.)

Your [finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) will be invoked during termination. This is a good place to handle clean-up.

Also see here for [how to use a cancellation token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#code-example) to stop a task when it is about to be cancelled.

Hope this helps.